# pyttsx3 giving no audio output

Tags: python, pyttsx3

*I've tried many different lines of code and can't get any output. It reads the mic just fine but won't say anything. I've been working on this for 3 days and can't get any speech out. I've also tried version 2.7 of pyttsx3 and the latest version, I"m on win 11*

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import pyttsx3

listener = sr.Recognizer()
engine = pyttsx3.init() #I've tried "dummy" and "sapi5" also
engine.setProperty('rate', 150)
engine.setProperty('volume', 1)

engine.say("What's up")
engine.runAndWait()
```

Comment: `engine.runAndWait` is a function, change it to `engine.runAndWait()`.

Comment: That didn't do it.  Before it even get's that far it should say 'What's up"

Comment: do you  get error message?  You could put `print(text)` after `say()` to see if it runs after `say()`. Maybe problem is hardware - your speakers. OR maybe problem is some audio driver in system. Or maybe it needs to install some C/C++ library to play sound.

Comment: Did the print and mic is working fine. Headphones work fine, I get audio from everything except this damn code.